# Creating shortcut to windows folder on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I am running Ubuntu alongside Windows 11. I often use Windows files and directories stored on the same computer but in different partitions. This is quite long because I have to navigate through the file manager and open the files. Is there any way to make a shortcut to a folder and put it on the Ubuntu partition? I already tried to use chmod but it gives me an error about permissions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is.

Mount the windows' partition. The file manager can do it automatically, but you need to do it on a permanent basis.

So first step, create a real directory in your file tree. Traditionally it is named something like `/mnt/win` or `/mnt/C`. Whatever you choose.

Run `fdisk -l`. It will list all partitions on you HDD and you need to take notice - what is the name of the windows' partition (column Device) and file system used on that partition (column Type).

Then mount the windows' partition into the created folder:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/C
```

Here the `ntfs` is a file system used by your Windows. `/dev/sdb1` is a name of a partition, and the `/mnt/C` is a directory where that partition is mounted. Now the root of your win' drive is in `/mnt/C`

If everything is fine - go `/etc/fstab` file and add there a line

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/C ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Now you can mount drive just by using its mount point

```
sudo mount /mnt/C
```

And it would be automatically mounted each time you boot your system.

And you can create as many symlinks from your $HOME to windows' folders as you like.

For more information, read `man mount`, `man mount.ntfs`, `man fstab`